# how to find the number of followers In Instagram through selenium web driver Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying the following code but running out with error "Unable to locate element"

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/ul/li[2]/span/span")).getText())

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following is working out well :-)

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span/span")).getAttribute("title"));

Shorter XPath :

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='react-root']//span[@title]")).getAttribute("title"));